# Insert Media - Attachment - Link to : Remove the "attachment page" option

Tags: attachments, links

I want to remove the *attachment page* option from the attachment's link-to selection.

I don't always want to tell my clients to avoid selecting this option, I simply want to take it out. But I am not programmer enough to do so. The Media File, Custom URL and None options are useful and should stay.

Does anyone know how to remove only the *attachment page* option there?

Answer (score 6):

These options are hardcoded into the `tmpl-attachment-display-settings` *Underscore* media template in the [`/wp-includes/media-template`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/media-template.php#L587) file:

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-attachment-display-settings">
    <h3><?php _e('Attachment Display Settings'); ?></h3>
    ...cut...
    <select class="link-to"             
            data-setting="link"
            <# if ( data.userSettings && ! data.model.canEmbed ) { #>
                data-user-setting="urlbutton"
            <# } #>>

        <# if ( data.model.canEmbed ) { #>
            <option value="embed" selected>
                <?php esc_attr_e('Embed Media Player'); ?>
            </option>
            <option value="file">
        <# } else { #>
            <option value="file" selected>
        <# } #>
        <# if ( data.model.canEmbed ) { #>
            <?php esc_attr_e('Link to Media File'); ?>
        <# } else { #>
            <?php esc_attr_e('Media File'); ?>
        <# } #>
            </option>
            <option value="post">
            <# if ( data.model.canEmbed ) { #>
                <?php esc_attr_e('Link to Attachment Page'); ?>
            <# } else { #>
                <?php esc_attr_e('Attachment Page'); ?>
            <# } #>
            </option>
            <# if ( 'image' === data.type ) { #>
                <option value="custom">
                    <?php esc_attr_e('Custom URL'); ?>
                </option>
                <option value="none">
                      <?php esc_attr_e('None'); ?>
                </option>
            <# } #>
        </select>
        ...cut...
</script>
```

You can always override the template by adding your own custom template, but I'm not sure how stable that would be, with respect to changes in the future.

If your `image_default_link_type` option is for example set to `file` and not `post`, then you could instead try to hide the *attachment page* option with some CSS hacks like:

```
/**
 * Hide the 'attachment page' option from the attachment link selection.
 * @see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/173027/26350
 */
add_action( 'print_media_templates', function(){
    echo '<style>.post-php select.link-to option[value="post"] {display:none;}</style>';
});
```

Then the link options would be:

**Before:**

[image: Before]

**After:**

[image: Hide attachment page option]

### Update:

In reply to the comment, we can handle both the *Add-* and *Edit* image media dialogs on the post edit screen with:

```
/**
 * Hide the 'Attachment Page' option for the link-to part.
 */

add_action( 'print_media_templates', function(){
    echo '
        <style>       
            .setting select.link-to option[value="post"],
            .setting select[data-setting="link"] option[value="post"] 
            { display: none; }
        </style>';
});
```

Comment: Dear birgire, thank you very much for your fast and comprehensive answer. I can only check it after the holy days and get back to you then, for the moment i wish you a merry christmas and a great start into 2015.

Comment: Ah yes sorry just didnt get back, it works perfect and makes me very happy :) Just that now recently I discovered that it appear at a new spot as well since WP restructured the media handling. So when adding a image newly to an article, it is out. But when clicking on the edit pen, in the following edit screen it still appears. Can we also adress it there with a second trick? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: aha, I see what you mean, please try the updated answer @Sofian

Comment: I updated my answer to also work on `post-new.php`

Comment: just the snippet under "update" does the trick for me. Thanks!