# Insert Media - Attachment - Link to : Remove options

Tags: media

I want to remove the Attachment page and Custom URL option from the attachment's link-to selection.

I simply want to take it out.  The Media File,  and None options are useful and should stay.

I found this answer to my question but it only works partly:

[Insert Media - Attachment - Link to : Remove the "attachment page" option](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173022/insert-media-attachment-link-to-remove-the-attachment-page-option/173027#173027)

It works fine for me on existing posts (a saved post, a concept post). On a new post however, a post that is not saved yet, all 4 display settings are shown. How can I fix this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I updated my answer you linked to. Hope it works now.

Comment: Thanks for your update, it works! While testing I noticed that when using my mobile (iPhone) to post or update still all 4 options are shown. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: Great. Are you using an app or accessing the backend via browser in your iphone? Please update you question accordingly, thanks.

Comment: Hi birgire, thanks for your quick response,  I was accessing via a browser on my iPhone.

Comment: Anyone else who can help me out on this one? Do I need to add a special <style> for mobile devices into my functions.php?